# How to include bootstrap values in phylogenetic trees in ape package

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap, phylogeny

I am using the R package `ape` to analyze some sequences stored in a DNAbin object:

```
library(ape)
my.seq  <- read.dna("sequences.txt", format = "clustal")
my.dist <- dist.dna(my.seq)
my.tree <- nj(my.dist)
```

I want to find the bootstrap values, so I use boot.phylo:

```
boot <- boot.phylo(my.tree, my.seq, FUN = function(xx) nj(dist.dna(xx)), B = 100)
```

But I get an error message saying:

```
Error in if (drop[j]) next : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Any idea what this means, and how to fix it? I tried googling the error message, and I could not find anything.

Comment: what package are you using?

Comment: It's the package ape, sorry I should have specified that!

Comment: Please make a reproducible example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your `if` condition resulted in an `NA`.

It must have either `TRUE` or `FALSE`result.